# How to dynamically create layouts inside screen in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote this python code to dyanamically create a BoxLayout inside a screen.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ListScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ListScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)          
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation ='vertical')
        top_buttons=BoxLayout()
        layout.add_widget(top_buttons) 
        top_buttons.add_widget(Button(text='Save'))

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):    
        root=ScreenManager()
        root.add_widget(ListScreen(name='list'))
        return root


ExampleApp().run()
```

It ran without any compilation error but the output is just a blank sreen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have not added `layout` to the `ListScreen` instance:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ListScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ListScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)          
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation ='vertical')
        self.add_widget(layout)                         #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        top_buttons=BoxLayout()
        layout.add_widget(top_buttons) 
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='Save'))

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):    
        root=ListScreen()
        root.add_widget(ListScreen(name='list'))
        return root


ExampleApp().run()
```